# In R: Refer to data, select, remove duplicates count

Tags: r, function

I am trying to confirm that my coding does the following: split the variable by commas (and other separators), collect values from another portion of the table, remove duplicates then count the data.

Now I believe I have done this. I have confirmed this works with another set of data, however, in this case there are comma separated values and therefore the manual Excel check and similarly broken down R check is doing my head in.

Here is the data:

```
structure(list(Vaccine.1.Valency = c("trivalent", "trivalent", 
"trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", 
"trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", 
"trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", 
"trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", 
"trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", 
"trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", 
"trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", 
"trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", 
"trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", 
"trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent"), Vaccine.2.Valency = c("quadrivalent", 
"quadrivalent", "quadrivalent", "quadrivalent", "quadrivalent", 
"quadrivalent", "quadrivalent", "quadrivalent", "quadrivalent", 
"quadrivalent", "quadrivalent", "quadrivalent", "quadrivalent", 
"quadrivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), Vaccine.3.Valency = c("trivalent", 
"trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", 
"trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", 
"trivalent", "trivalent", "trivalent", "quadrivalent", "quadrivalent", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", ""), Vaccine.4.Valency = c("quadrivalent", "quadrivalent", 
"quadrivalent", "quadrivalent", "quadrivalent", "quadrivalent", 
"quadrivalent", "quadrivalent", "quadrivalent", "quadrivalent", 
"quadrivalent", "quadrivalent", "quadrivalent", "quadrivalent", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", ""), Vaccine.5.Valency = c("", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), Vaccine.6.Valency = c("", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
""), Vaccine.... = c("1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", 
"2", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "all vaccines", "all vaccines", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1")), row.names = c(NA, 50L
), class = "data.frame")
```

**NB putting the above in as.data.frame() should work for reproducibility.

My coding logic is as follows: convert numbers to valencies, remove duplicates across rows (so each row only has for example trivalent show up once), then count types of valencies total (once again with value only being allowed to show up once per row.

My coding (includes function as I redid this with several variables):

```
# __ *Fun
URD_FUN <- function(Tab, col_no){ # URD: Unite, Remove Duplicates
  Tab_fun <- Tab %>% 
    unite(L, col_no, sep = ', ', remove = TRUE)
  Tab_fun$L <- vapply(strsplit(Tab_fun$L, ', '),
                      function(x) paste(unique(x),
                                        collapse = ', '), character(1L))
  return(Tab_fun)
}

Unlist_Tab_FUN <- function(TabVar){
  DF <- as.data.frame(table(unlist(strsplit(as.character(TabVar), ','))))
  DF$Var1 <- gsub('(^[[:space:]]*)|([[:space:]]*$)', '', DF$Var1)
  DF <- DF %>%
    group_by(Var1) %>% summarise(Freq_all = sum(Freq))
  return(DF)
}


To$Vaccine.... <- gsub(';| and|and | or', ',', To$Vaccine....)
To <- cSplit(To, 'Vaccine....', sep = ',',
                  fixed = TRUE, type.convert = FALSE)
colnames(To)[7]
To <- To %>% 
  mutate_at(c(7), trimws)
To <- To %>% 
  mutate(across(c(7), ~ case_when(
    . == 1 ~ Vaccine.1.Valency[],
    . == 2 ~ Vaccine.2.Valency[],
    . == 3 ~ Vaccine.3.Valency[],
    . == 4 ~ Vaccine.4.Valency[],
    . == 5 ~ Vaccine.5.Valency[],
    . == 6 ~ Vaccine.6.Valency[],
    str_detect(., 'vac|Vac|All') ~ paste(
      Vaccine.1.Valency[],Vaccine.2.Valency[],Vaccine.3.Valency[],
      Vaccine.4.Valency[],Vaccine.5.Valency[],Vaccine.6.Valency[],
      sep = ', '))))
To$Vaccine...._1[To$Vaccine...._1 == 'trivalent and quadrivalent'] <- 'trivalent, quadrivalent'

To <- To[,c(7)]
To <- URD_FUN(To, 1)
To$L
as.data.frame(table(unlist(strsplit(as.character(To$L), ','))))
```

Can anyone confirm that this method produces the right value / my coding logic is working.

NB much smaller list so some columns removed in code

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
This is one method that answers the question

```
MDF.1[,Valency:=sapply(
  strsplit(as.character(MDF.1$Valency), split = ',\\s*|,'),
  function(x) {paste(unique(x), collapse = ', ')})]
```